# Javascript date format issue 2018-04-11T17:47:00+0200

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such date format as `2018-04-11T17:47:00+0200`

What format is?

And how to generate it dynamically till the end of day?

for example

```
 var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999);
```

Comment: "What format is?" - [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1):

It is a date and time in standard ISO format (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
It is the date followed by the time with timezone.
The timezone +0200 means that the time 17:47:00 is exactly two hours ahead of the reference UTC time (which gets the suffix 'Z')
So, in this case 17:47:00+0200 describes the same point in time as 15:47:00Z

If you want to set the time in a javascript `Date`object, you can do it by calling methods:

```
d.setHours(23);
d.setMinutes(59);
d.setSeconds(59)
d.setMilliseconds(999)
```

The javascript function `Date.getISOString()` returns the date in ISO format, but it always creates it in UTC time zone:

```
new Date(Date.parse('2018-04-11T17:47:00+0200')).toISOString()
=> "2018-04-11T15:47:00.000Z"
```